# Choosing a controller for a layout class instance variable in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, layout, controller, partial-views, class-instance-variables

I have a DateTime class instance variable `@current_year = DateTime.now.year`, which I have set into a footer partial. This partial is rendered across several of my clientside pages (and across multiple controllers as `<%= render 'layouts/page_footer' %>` in the main body of the page - the layout/application.html.erb page is reserved for the site navigation, so the format will not accommodate it there. While I could declare it for every page method it appears on in the controller, I'd find something a little more DRY. Is there a single place I can define my time variable to call in my layout component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *could* add a `set_year` action in your `ApplicationController`, something like:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base 

  private 

    def set_year 
      @current_year = DateTime.now.year
    end

end
```

And then call it in a `before_action` in your relevant controller actions. Something like:

```
class FooController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_year, only: [:some_action, :another_action]
end
```

Alternatively and riffing off MrYoshiji's comment, you could create a `current_year` action in `ApplicationController`, something like:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  def current_year
    @current_year ||= DateTime.now.year
  end

end
```

In which case, you could use `current_year` in your partial instead of `@current_year`. And then, as MrYoshiji says, you could move that into a helper if that sort of things floats your boat. Something like:

```
module ApplicationHelper

  def current_year
    @current_year ||= DateTime.now.year
  end

end
```

The upside, I suppose, of moving `current_year` into a helper is that it de-clutters your `ApplicationController`. The downside, I further suppose, is that it obsfucates (to some degree), the source of the `current_year` action. Again, you'll have to take your boat floating coefficient into consideration.

BTW, `@current_year` isn't a `DateTime`. It's a `Fixnum`.

Comment: or a helper, kind of like how `current_user` is defined: `def current_year ; @current_year ||= DateTime.now.year ; end` in the `ApplicationHelper`.

Answer (score 1):

you could create a method in application_helper.rb file
and use it anywhere you like.

```
def current_year
  @current_year = DateTime.now.year
end
```

Comment: I used the other one since my boat floating coefficient has to factor in sourcing and junior devs not necessarily being familiar with helpers, but I really like this answer for future purposes! My current Application controller is two methods long, so in this case not so much an issue. :)